# simulating/emulating a heavily loaded database server in postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql

I have a need to test my application(written in c# .net) behavior when the database server (postgres 9.3) takes a long time to return data for queries.

I do not want to change the application code or queries or the database schema.

Is there a way to simulate that the database server is loaded and simulate a delay in returning data ?

Comment: A quick way can be this: via pgadmin or your favorite client you start a transaction, then update a table that will be involved in your application. You start application that cannot update same rows. You can commit or rollback transaction when you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pgbench` program with a high number of clients to impose a high actual load on the server.  This will create new tables, but they can but into a different schema or even a different database within the database cluster.  (Or if you can't even add tables into a different database, you could even run a separate database instance on a different port on the same computer server, and load that one up.)

If you initialize the pgbench schema with a large scale factor so the data doesn't fit in RAM, this will create high IO load.  If you use a small scale factor, it will create high CPU load.